# JS trigger only affecting parent and siblings

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

**Context :** I have a section of a slider before-after working, targeting a class and affecting the css properties of the parent or sibling. However when I duplicate the same section the second obviously affect the first slider. I want to be able to duplicate my section many times without have to touch the code each time.

**What I know :** querySelector only find the first element. So I started to use querySelectorAll but as it's affecting other class of sibling and parent I start to be really confused.

**What I am wondering :** How can I make each trigger affect only his parent and sibling properties ? Should I create differents css class for each slider ?

**What I did :** I did a codepen with two sections to allow you to have a better understanding of my problem and eventualy try it out. https://codepen.io/greg_o/pen/KGOKvG

My JS

```
let active = false;


var scrollers = document.querySelectorAll('.scroller');

scrollers.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mousedown',function scrolling(){
    active = true;
    element.classList.add('scrolling');
  });
});


document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});


document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});


document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
  if (!active) return;
  let x = e.pageX;
  x -= document.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollIt(x);
});


function scrollIt(x){
    let transform = Math.max(0,(Math.min(x,document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetWidth)));
    document.querySelector('.after').style.width = 'calc(' + transform + 'px + 35vw)';
    document.querySelector('.scroller').style.left = transform-25+"px";
}


scrollIt(300);
```

My CSS

```
#slider{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .wrapper{
        width: 30vw;
        height: 20vw;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .before, .after {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-color: white;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        pointer-events:none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content-image{
        height:100%;
    }

    .after{
        transform: skewX(-30deg) translate(-35vw); 
    }

    .content-image.apres{
        transform: skewX(30deg) translate(35vw);
    }

    .scroller{
        width: 50px;
        height:50px;
        position: absolute;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        border-radius:50%;
        background-color: transparent;
        opacity:0.9;
        pointer-events:auto;
        cursor: move;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
    }

    .scroller:hover{
        opacity:1;
    }

    .scrolling{
        pointer-events:none;
        opacity:1;
        // z-index: 1;
    }

    .scroller__thumb{
        margin:0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .scroller:before, .scroller:after{
        background: #fff;
        content:" ";
        display: block;
        width: 3px;
        height: 9999px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -3.5px;
        z-index: 30;
        transition:0.1s;
    }
    .scroller:before{
        top:95%;
        left:28%;
        transform-origin:top;
        transform:rotate(30deg)
    }
    .scroller:after{
        bottom:95%;
        left:83%;
        transform-origin:bottom;
        transform:rotate(30deg)
    }
```

My HTML

```
<section id="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="before">
    <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
  <div class="after">
    <img class="content-image apres" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
  </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="before">
    <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
  <div class="after">
    <img class="content-image apres" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
  </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You could use something like `element.parentElement.getElementsByClass("after")[0].doSomething()

Comment: Use multiple instances. querySelectorAll and reference each slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem by passing `document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling")[0].parentNode` in `ScrollIt` method. And use that parameter to find the related `.after` and `.wrapper` elements.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxMBbX).

```js
let active = false;


var scrollers = document.querySelectorAll('.scroller');

scrollers.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mousedown',function scrolling(){
    active = true;
    element.classList.add('scrolling');
  });
});


document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scrolling').classList.remove('scrolling');
});


document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});


document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
  if (!active) return;
  let x = e.pageX;
  x -= document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling")[0].parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollIt(document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling")[0].parentNode, x);
});


function scrollIt(elem, x){
    let transform = Math.max(0,(Math.min(x,elem.offsetWidth)));
    elem.querySelector('.after').style.width = 'calc(' + transform + 'px + 35vw)';
    elem.querySelector('.scroller').style.left = transform-25+"px";
}
scrollIt(document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0] ,300);
scrollIt(document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[1] ,20);
```

```css
#slider{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }
  
 .wrapper{
    width: 30vw;
    height: 20vw;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }
 
 .before, .after {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 .content-image{
    height:100%;
 }
 
 .after{
    transform: skewX(-30deg) translate(-35vw); 
 }
 
 .content-image.apres{
    transform: skewX(30deg) translate(35vw);
 }
 
 .scroller{
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity:0.9;
    pointer-events:auto;
    cursor: move;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
 }
 
 .scroller:hover{
    opacity:1;
 }
 
 .scrolling{
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:1;
  // z-index: 1;
 }

 .scroller__thumb{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:5px;
 }
 
 .scroller:before, .scroller:after{
  background: #fff;
  content:" ";
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.5px;
  z-index: 30;
  transition:0.1s;
 }
 .scroller:before{
    top:95%;
    left:28%;
    transform-origin:top;
    transform:rotate(30deg)
 }
 .scroller:after{
    bottom:95%;
    left:83%;
    transform-origin:bottom;
    transform:rotate(30deg)
 }
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="before">
    <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
  <div class="after">
    <img class="content-image apres" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
  </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="before">
    <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
  <div class="after">
    <img class="content-image apres" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
  </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Alright, I have to say that everything works perfectly even if I change the wrapper size which is super handy! Once again thanks a lot!

Comment: You got it buddy!

Comment: May I can ask you how `document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling")[0].parentNode` know that it's not the first child ? because to me [0] means the first one he finds ? I am wrong ?

Comment: I mean when it's finding wrapper I don't know how it knows which wrapper it is

Comment: So basically this line `x -= document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling")[0].parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().left;`

Comment: `docuement.getElementsByClassName` will return an array of the class we are looking for. In out case, we are adding `scrolling` class on mouse down. So there will be only **one** scrolling class at a time. So you can use [0] or you can use `document.querySelector('.scrolling')`

Comment: So for particular that line you can use `x -= document.querySelector('.scrolling').parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().left;` also

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, I didn't pay attention that it was scrolling and not scroller! Man this is genius! You are a really altruistic thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I perfome some changes to your codepen, now it works fine.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqgZmO.

```
let active = false;


var scrollers = document.querySelectorAll('.scroller');
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

scrollers.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mousedown',function scrolling(){
    active = true;
    element.classList.add('scrolling');
  });
});

sliders.forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
          active = false;
          element.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
     });

      element.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
          active = false;
          element.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
      });


      element.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
         if (!active) return;
              let x = e.pageX;
              x -= element.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left;
              scrollIt(x,element);
     });

});


function scrollIt(x, element){
    let transform = Math.max(0,(Math.min(x,document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetWidth)));
    element.querySelector('.after').style.width = 'calc(' + transform + 'px + 35vw)';
    element.querySelector('.scroller').style.left = transform-25+"px";
}


scrollIt(300);
```

The problem is, you are using the same id for two sliders (id="slider"), and you add event to document.body. in the future try to focus your event on one element, in our case sliders.

Hope that's help.
Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me a lot, I understood that I should have use element as a parameter and that I should have think about accessing to my .after class by using his parents. You resolve it by another way which is pretty cool for me to know! Thanks a lot!